# The result of 'locale' command differs between inside and outside docker container

Tags: docker

The result of 'locale' command differs between when I execute it in docker container and when I execute it in outside of docker container.

And when I run a python script in that container the script is executed well, but when I run that script from outside of that container UnicodeEncodeError happens.

I made the docker container from this docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install some basic utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a working directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-root user and switch to it
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# Install Miniconda
RUN curl -so ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false

# Create a Python 3.6 environment
RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py36 python=3.6.5 \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=py36
ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda/envs/$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

# No CUDA-specific steps
ENV NO_CUDA=1
RUN conda install -y -c pytorch \
    pytorch-cpu=1.0.0 \
    torchvision-cpu=0.2.1 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install HDF5 Python bindings
RUN conda install -y h5py=2.8.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip install h5py-cache==1.0

# Install Torchnet, a high-level framework for PyTorch
RUN pip install torchnet==0.0.4

# Install Requests, a Python library for making HTTP requests
RUN conda install -y requests=2.19.1 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install Graphviz
RUN conda install -y graphviz=2.38.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip install graphviz==0.8.4

# Install OpenCV3 Python bindings
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libcanberra-gtk-module \
 && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Set the default command to python3
CMD ["python3"]
```

and changed locale by this command

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-ja-base language-pack-ja
sudo locale-gen ja_JP.UTF-8

sudo echo export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 >> ~/.profile
sudo source ~/.profile
sudo date
```

When I execute

```
docker exec -it adoring_wilson /bin/bash -c "locale"
```

from outside of container, the result is

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

When I execute

```
docker exec -it adoring_wilson /bin/bash
```

and execute this inside container

```
locale
```

the result is

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: `man bash`: "When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the  file  /etc/profile, if  that  file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile, in that  order,  and  reads  and  executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."

Answer (score 0):

That's because your first command is ran in a interactive *non-login shell*. Thus, the **.profile** file is not processed.
If you want to load the variable anyway, you'll have to use the **.bashrc** file.

You can find a more detailled answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176404/bash-not-loading-profile-in-new-session-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I could execute my script from outside of container correctly by attaching '--login' .